# Clicking on Span element in selenium which is inside <a href> tag

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click on Span element link which is exiting inside  tag. I tried it by copied Path but its didn't go through. Can you please help me to solve it

I tried it by using following code:
1.

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[@class='wrapper']/header[@class='header-fixed']/div[@class='container']/ul[@class='control-bar']/li[1]/a[@href='/login']/span[text()='LOG in']")).click();
```

2. 

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'help') and text()='LOG in']")).click();
```

Comment: In order to help you we need to see all your Selenium code including the link to the page you are working on

Comment: my HTML code is:         <body class="main-template" style="">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header>
                <div class="container">
                    <ul class="control-bar">
                        <li><a href="/login" class="btn border"><span class="help">LOG in</span></a></li>

Comment: This is absolutely not enough

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You have to add a bit more detail, this is very vague and one can't tell what's really going on. But to be sure you're using the right XPATH variable, you can inspect the button on the webpage, right click and copy XPath